# Does "laser car wash " use actual lasers?

Tags: car, carwash

Just wondering since it's called laser car wash if they use actual lasers to wash the car ?

Comment: Laser alignment maybe?  One of several ways that the machine can know where and how big your car is, so as not to crash into it or spray from too far away.

Comment: Yes, but they are set to 'stun' to avoid damaging your vehicle.

Answer (score 4):

LaserWash is a brand name for a touchless car wash system, which uses high pressure water and strong detergents instead of the traditional soap and rolling sponge gizmos. No lasers are used.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there are no lasers used here. It's just the new technology in the carwash industry. As I see it includes 4 stages: pre-soak=> spray the detergent=> pressure rinse => high pressure dryer. It's not harming your car much like the traditional way